# PhpSpreadsheet: How to change plotStyle and other options

Tags: phpspreadsheet

I would like to customize a ScatterPlot chart within my xlsx spreadsheet.  I have used the sample ScatterPlot code for PhpSpreadsheet to get started.  One minor modification to the sample code was to change the the new Chart displayBlanksAs parameter from 0 to 'gap'.  This is a know error in the samples code:

[File containing a chart can not be opened by Excel 2003/2013/2019](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/1337)

[33_Chart_create_scatter.php](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/master/samples/Chart/33_Chart_create_scatter.php)

[image]

I have many questions, but I will ask just a couple and then maybe I can figure out the rest.

**Question #1:** How to change the ScatterPlot plotStyle from Line & Marker to just markers? I assumed I could change it from DataSeries::STYLE_LINEMARKER to DataSeries::STYLE_MARKER.  But that didn't change anything.

```
        $series = new DataSeries(
             DataSeries::TYPE_SCATTERCHART,
             null,
             range(0, count($dataSeriesValues) - 1),
             $dataSeriesLabels,
             $xAxisTickValues,
             $dataSeriesValues,
             null,
             null,
             DataSeries::STYLE_LINEMARKER // Can I change to STYLE_MARKER?
         );
```

**Question #2:**.How do I remove the yAxis horizontal major gridlines?

Comment: I have performed further investigation and documenting under the PhpSpreadsheet issues on github:  https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/1431

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have spent all day tracing it down to the OpenXml data and found the changes I need to make to answer Question #1.

[This is how I debugged the xlsx](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/1431#issuecomment-606993900)

[Here is how I modified PhpSpreadsheet to fix it](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/1431#issuecomment-607013891)

I will attempt to submit a pull request, once I can remember how to do it.